# Component not updating after state change

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-testing-library

Please help! I spent the whole day and still can't wrap my head over this test. All I need is to test an error state.
I mock my mutation to return an err and then check if there's err alert on the screen. (Everything works fine in browser)
Here's my test

```
    test("Duplicate config error", async () => {
      mockMutation(AddNewConfigDocument, {
        Mutation: {
          addNewConfig: () => {
            throw new Error("A matching configuration already exists.")
          },
        },
      })

      render(<ClauseDetails clauseId={clauseId} />)

      ...
      const createBtn = await screen.findByText("Create")
      expect(createBtn).toBeInTheDocument()
      userEvent.click(createBtn) // this triggers mutation

      expect(await screen.findByText("A matching configuration already exists.", undefined, { timeout: 5000 })).toBeInTheDocument()
    }, 10000)
```

simplified component

```
...
  const defaultErrorState = { hasError: false, message: "" }
  const [errorState, setError] = useState<ErrorStateType>(defaultErrorState)

    const onError = (error: ApolloError) => {
     updateErrorState(true, getErrorAlertMessage(error.message))
     refetch()
    }

  const [addNewConfig, { loading }] = useAddNewConfigMutation({
    onError,
    onCompleted,
  })
```

what I see in the console when running test

```
    // my mock mutation works
    custom mock response:  {
      "errors": [
        {
          "message": "A matching configuration already exists.",
          "locations": [],
          "path": [
            "addConfig"
          ]
        }
      ],
      "data": {
        "addConfig": null
      }
    }


  console.log
    { errorStateHasError: false }


  console.log
    { errorStateHasError: true }
```

Then test fails here where err state just realized it has an err on line where I'm trying to `findByText("A matching configuration already exists.")`

Comment: Show the code of `ClauseDetails` component under test.

Answer (score 1):

yes there is a way you need to get `isError` from `useMutation` and create a `useEffect`.

`const {isError} = useMutation()`
`useEffect(()=>{if(isError){setState()}},[isError])`